# How to serve a vue project to other computers on the network

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I am very new to vue.js.

I have made a couple of small projects and I would like to be sure I understand how I actually serve a vue project to other users at this point.

Of course, I know I can type 'npm run serve' in my project directory and it will serve it to localhost:80XX. That is what I've been doing since I started working with vue a couple days ago. However, when I do this the network line under the 'local: localhost:8080' just reads 'network: unavailable', so I am obviously not broadcasting on anything another computer can connect to and receive from.

How does this basically work? Do I have to build it with npm run build and then use firebase or something similar to broadcast the contents of my dist folder out to the user? Searching online produced some pretty confusing results, I ended up with more questions than answers.

I basically would just like to show my coworkers what I have made with vue, what is the way to do this without taking a shortcut? I would like to do this in a way that I will be able to understand in the future how to do this with a fully fledged project.

Thank you!

edit: if there is a tutorial or a link that discusses this directly, please feel free to refer me to it! I was unable to find this being discussed at the level I'm at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary), the default HOST that Vue binds to, is `0.0.0.0`, which means that anyone in your network can see your server.

What you can do is find your network ip address, and share with others.

To do so, you can do, in Windows:

1. Open your terminal
2. Type:

```
ipconfig
```

3. Grab the `IPv4` address of your network
4. Share the link with your colleagues in the form: `http://<IP_ADDRESS>:8080`

This way, they can connect to your running develop instance.

Comment: but if it is saying "network:unavailable" when I run "npm run serve" will this still work?

Comment: Ok so that worked. Thank you, @Gustavo Lopes. However, I'm still not clear on what the 'network:unavailable' means or how I get that working to broadcast on the web. 
I know that I have to build something before I can serve it as a production webpage, but how do I serve the results of a build? (I assume 'npm run build' it puts everything in my dist folder)

Comment: This is a whole other subject. You have to create a server to serve the files for you. `npm run serve` creates a develop server, which is insecure and slow (you should NEVER use it in production). What you can do is use some develop servers available out there. [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) is a great tool that can help you (it is again insecure and slow, but for development purposes, it works)

Comment: To use it, you install it `npm i -g http-server` and then `http-server --host 0.0.0.0 /dist`

Comment: perfect. Thank you, Gustavo!